# Monitor creation of child process from CMD parent in WinDbg

Tags: windbg, child-process

Not sure about the procedure on how to perform monitorization of child processes in WindDBG. I need to know how I can monitor the creation of child processes from CMD.exe parent using conditional breakpoints in WinDBG.

In this case I need to use bp nt!NtCreateUserProcess and the idea is to use command j (if-else). Basically, I need to print a message in case there is a creation of CMD.Exe process (child process) and if not, continue the debugging (g). I only need to monitor CMD.exe child processes and I need to ask for it in a if-else loop if possible.

I want to monitor the creation of processes in Windbg which have CMD.exe as the parent process considering kernel debugging. I know the function to be used in Windbg is !NtCreateUserProcess but I'm not sure which field needs to be used for that purpose considering the attributes of the function.

There is a  PsAttributeValue(PsAttributeParentProcess) in the attributes structure based on the following source: https://captmeelo.com//redteam/maldev/2022/05/10/ntcreateuserprocess.html but not sure if this is an ID or the process name. Could it be used in this case?

Basically, considering command j (if-else) it must be something like:

bp nt!NtCreateUserProcess "j (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) '.printf "New CMD process child!!\n ---->%mu\n" ; ' .printf "No New CMD process child!!\n ---->%mu\n"; g' "

Can you please provide me some clues?

Thanks.
Regards.

Comment: The main problem for you is to know if you're in the right process context (that is, if the caller is cmd.exe). Windbg `$proc` pseudo register is a pointer to an `_EPROCESS` structure (you'll have to cast $proc)  where the `ImageFileName` field is a string to the image file name (e.g. `cmd.exe`). This won't help to discriminate between the "real" cmd.exe and a dummy process named as such though (getting the full path to the image is possible but way more complicated). From there NtCreateUserProcess `ProcessParameters` or `AttributeList` will give you more information about the started process.

Comment: Do you know if the 448th offset of EPROCESS contains the name of the process (parent process), basically the image name you are referring to? Is this the parent process field I am looking for?

Comment: 1/ hmm I think we're not on the same track: if you want to track which processes are created by `cmd.exe` by setting a BP on `NtCreateUserProcess ` you'll need to check if the **current** process is `cmd.exe` (because cmd.exe is currently trying to spawn a new process). concerning the offset, cast the `$proc` to a `nt!_EPROCESS` structure because the fields offset change a lot in these internal structure (e.g. on my Windows version, +0x448 in EPROCESS is `ActiveProcessLinks` which is the doubly linked list of running processes).

Comment: 2/ I think the way you've chosen is probably the least complex one if you want to do it in kernel, from a debugger. There are other ways to check when a process is created, which process is its originator, but you would need to understand the system internals (e.g. intercepting process insertion in the doubly linked list).

Comment: But here the imageFileName is : System not CMD.exe... This is another additional doubt I have

Comment: Ok, so I did something like : dt nt!_eprocess 8854e880 (Address of cmd.exe process) and I receive the following: +0x17c ImageFileName : [15] "System". I guess the offset is 0x17c and I need to take (rcx+17c) to get the ImageFileName right? Correct me if I am wrong, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a deep grudge against Windbg's OG scripting language, so here's a [JS script for Windbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/javascript-debugger-scripting).

Tested on a fully up to date Win10 22H2 machine. I guess it may work on other windows versions / updates (at least Win 10 and Win 11), but nothing is guaranteed.

You'll need a rather recent version of Windbg or Windbg preview.

- This is a script which can only be used for kernel debugging.
- Have your kernel debugger attached to the target machine.
- Copy / paste the script in its own file (e.g. `c:\tmp\windbg_script.js`) on your **host**.
- Break in the debugger.
- Load & run the script using [`.scriptload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/javascript-debugger-scripting#scriptload-load-script).
- Once the script is loaded, run the target (`g`).
- You should see `---- invokescript ----` printed in your debugger output.
- Now the target machine is running, spawn a `cmd.exe` and start whatever process you want.
- If a process is spawned by `cmd.exe` the script will print some information and stop the debugger.
- If a process is started **but not by cmd.exe** it just prints `[not CMD]` and continue execution (without breaking into the debugger).

```js
"use strict";

function initializeScript()
{
    return [new host.apiVersionSupport(1, 7)];
}

let logln = function (e) {
    host.diagnostics.debugLog(e + '\n');
}

function read_u64(addr) {
    return host.memory.readMemoryValues(addr, 1, 8)[0];
}

function handle_bp() {
    let retVal = false; // continue exec by default.

    if(host.currentProcess.Name === "cmd.exe")
    {
        logln("Process spawned by CMD!");

        // read RSP
        let cpuRegs = host.currentThread.Registers.User;
        let rsp = cpuRegs.rsp;
        logln("RSP: 0x" + rsp.toString(16));

        // RSP + 0x48 is "ProcessParameters" location on the stack.
        let procParamAddr = rsp.add(0x48);
        logln("ProcessParamAddr (on stack): 0x" + procParamAddr.toString(16));
        let procParam = read_u64(procParamAddr);
        logln("procParam: 0x" + procParam.toString(16));

        // procParam + 0x68 hold a string to the full path of the process that will be started.
        let procPathAddr = procParam.add(0x68);
        logln("procPathAddr: 0x" + procPathAddr.toString(16));
        let procPath = read_u64(procPathAddr);
        logln("procPath: 0x" + procPath.toString(16));

        // now read the string.
        let procPathString = host.memory.readWideString(procPath);
        logln("CMD Spawned the following process: " + procPathString);
        retVal = true; // stop exec
    }
    else 
    {
        logln("[not CMD]");
        //host.namespace.Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand("g");
    }

    return retVal;    
}

function invokeScript()
{
    // startup
    logln("---- invokescript ----");
    let Control = host.namespace.Debugger.Utility.Control;
    let CurrentProcess = host.currentProcess;
    let NtCreateUserProcess = host.getModuleSymbolAddress('nt', 'NtCreateUserProcess');
    let BreakpointAlreadySet = CurrentProcess.Debug.Breakpoints.Any(
        c => c.Address == NtCreateUserProcess
    );
    if(BreakpointAlreadySet == false) {
        logln('NtCreateUserProcess: 0x' + NtCreateUserProcess.toString(16));
        Control.ExecuteCommand('bp /w "@$scriptContents.handle_bp()" ' + NtCreateUserProcess.toString(16));
    } else {
        logln('Breakpoint already set.');
    }
    logln('Press "g" to run the target.');

}
```

so the main stuff happens in `handle_bp()`.

First we just check we're in cmd.exe context, otherwise we bail out (this is the same things as checking the `ImageFileName` from the `_EPROCESS` structure):

```
if(host.currentProcess.Name === "cmd.exe")
```

After that it gets a bit complicated, so here's the breakdown:

Once we're sure we're in the `cmd.exe` context and with our BP on `nt!NtCreateUserProcess`:

```
NtCreateUserProcess(
    _Out_ PHANDLE ProcessHandle,  // rcx
    _Out_ PHANDLE ThreadHandle,  // rdx
    _In_ ACCESS_MASK ProcessDesiredAccess,  // r8
    _In_ ACCESS_MASK ThreadDesiredAccess,   // r9
    _In_opt_ POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ProcessObjectAttributes,
    _In_opt_ POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ThreadObjectAttributes,
    _In_ ULONG ProcessFlags,
    _In_ ULONG ThreadFlags,
    _In_ PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS ProcessParameters,
    _Inout_ PPS_CREATE_INFO CreateInfo,
    _In_ PPS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST AttributeList
);
```

(side note: in the example below, I started `ping 127.0.0.1` from `cmd.exe`)

The 1st 4 params by registers (nothing really interesting), the reminder on the stack. Here's an example of the state of the stack at BP:

```
2: kd> dqs @rsp
fffffd82`7e537448  fffff802`5c80d8f5 nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25 +0x00
fffffd82`7e537450  00000000`00000002  // (shadow space)             +0x08
fffffd82`7e537458  00000000`00000001                                +0x10
fffffd82`7e537460  00000000`00000000                                +0x18
fffffd82`7e537468  0000014f`f4df28e0                                +0x20
fffffd82`7e537470  00000000`00000000  // ProcessObjectAttributes    +0x28
fffffd82`7e537478  00000000`00000000  // ThreadObjectAttributes     +0x30
fffffd82`7e537480  0000000c`00000204  // ProcessFlags               +0x38
fffffd82`7e537488  00000000`00000001  // ThreadFlags                +0x40
fffffd82`7e537490  0000014f`f4df28e0  // ProcessParameters          +0x48
fffffd82`7e537498  0000000c`9856de70  // CreateInfo                 +0x50
fffffd82`7e5374a0  0000000c`9856e660  // AttributeList              +0x58
fffffd82`7e5374a8  00000000`00000001
fffffd82`7e5374b0  00000000`00000000
```

Pointer at `AttributeList`+0x18 gives you the full path of the program that is started:

```
2: kd> dq c`9856e660
0000000c`9856e660  00000000`00000088 00000000`00020005
0000000c`9856e670  00000000`00000040 0000014f`f4deb740
0000000c`9856e680  00000000`00000000 00000000`00010003
0000000c`9856e690  00000000`00000010 0000000c`9856df20
0000000c`9856e6a0  00000000`00000000 00000000`00000006
0000000c`9856e6b0  00000000`00000040 0000000c`9856e060
0000000c`9856e6c0  00000000`00000000 00000000`0006001a
0000000c`9856e6d0  00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001

2: kd> db 0000014f`f4deb740
0000014f`f4deb740  5c 00 3f 00 3f 00 5c 00-43 00 3a 00 5c 00 57 00  \.?.?.\.C.:.\.W.
0000014f`f4deb750  69 00 6e 00 64 00 6f 00-77 00 73 00 5c 00 73 00  i.n.d.o.w.s.\.s.
0000014f`f4deb760  79 00 73 00 74 00 65 00-6d 00 33 00 32 00 5c 00  y.s.t.e.m.3.2.\.
0000014f`f4deb770  50 00 49 00 4e 00 47 00-2e 00 45 00 58 00 45 00  P.I.N.G...E.X.E.
```

Below is `ProcessParameters`:

```
2: kd> dq 14f`f4df28e0
0000014f`f4df28e0  000006f0`000006f0 00000000`00000001
0000014f`f4df28f0  00000000`00000048 00000000`00000000
0000014f`f4df2900  00000000`00000050 00000000`00000054
0000014f`f4df2910  00000000`00000058 00000000`02080020
0000014f`f4df2920  0000014f`f4df2d20 00000000`00000000
0000014f`f4df2930  00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000
0000014f`f4df2940  00000000`003a0038 0000014f`f4df2f28
0000014f`f4df2950  00000000`0020001e 0000014f`f4df2f68
```

`ProcessParameters`+0x68 gives you the same info:

```
2: kd> db 14f`f4df2f28
0000014f`f4df2f28  43 00 3a 00 5c 00 57 00-69 00 6e 00 64 00 6f 00  C.:.\.W.i.n.d.o.
0000014f`f4df2f38  77 00 73 00 5c 00 73 00-79 00 73 00 74 00 65 00  w.s.\.s.y.s.t.e.
0000014f`f4df2f48  6d 00 33 00 32 00 5c 00-50 00 49 00 4e 00 47 00  m.3.2.\.P.I.N.G.
0000014f`f4df2f58  2e 00 45 00 58 00 45 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ..E.X.E.........
```

Pointer at `ProcessParameters`+0x78 gives you the entire command line of the process that is started (as given in cmd.exe console window):

```
0000014f`f4df2f68  70 00 69 00 6e 00 67 00-20 00 20 00 31 00 32 00  p.i.n.g. . .1.2.
0000014f`f4df2f78  37 00 2e 00 30 00 2e 00-30 00 2e 00 31 00 00 00  7...0...0...1...
```

In the script I decided to simply go for `ProcessParameters` +0x68. You 'll need to change the offsets or parameter if you want the full command line.

The script is very chaty, but this is helpful to understand what's going on (also execution stops if the parent process is `cmd.exe`, but you can change that).

Output sample after loading the script:

```
---- invokescript ----
NtCreateUserProcess: 0xfffff80248a145a0
Press "g" to run the target.
0: kd> g
[not CMD]
[not CMD]
[not CMD]
[not CMD]
[not CMD]
[not CMD]
[not CMD]
[not CMD]
[not CMD]
[not CMD]
[not CMD]
[not CMD]
[not CMD]
[not CMD]
... // yeah, a lot of process are started on a Windows machine...
    // now starting ping on the machine (in cmd.exe)
Process spawned by CMD!
RSP: 0xffffa384c47d8448
ProcessParamAddr (on stack): 0xffffa384c47d8490
procParam: 0x17bf1d00e90
procPathAddr: 0x17bf1d00ef8
procPath: 0x17bf1d014d8
CMD Spawned the following process: C:\Windows\system32\PING.EXE
Breakpoint 0 hit
// ...
// starting calc from cmd.exe
Process spawned by CMD!
RSP: 0xffffa384c47d8448
ProcessParamAddr (on stack): 0xffffa384c47d8490
procParam: 0x17bf1d00e90
procPathAddr: 0x17bf1d00ef8
procPath: 0x17bf1d014d8
CMD Spawned the following process: C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
Breakpoint 0 hit
```

Comment: It is clear I don't have the same expertise as you with Windbg that's the reason why I have quite a few questions: 1/How do you execute cmd.exe ping 127.0.0.1? Do you continue the debugging until Windows Debugee is unlocked? 2/How do you execute this script? It would be helpful a video or something like that as for me it is difficult to follow the whole procedure followed. Perhaps, after seen it, this is much more clear for me. Anyway perhaps I am asking too much. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1939837 I added some details in the answer. You should also try to follow the first link in my answer which explains the basics about loading and executing JS windbg scripts. Concerning 1/ execute the script, run the target machine and (now that it is executing normally) execute whatever you want from cmd. 2/ added some info & links in the answer.

Comment: Ok, it seems that now it works. For some reason, it was not working at the beginning. Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: @user1939837 Glad it worked, Windbg's JS scripts may be a bit fiddly if you're not used to them. If you think this answer does answer your question, you may to accept it (I'm not specifically after internet points, but more just for the sake of having really and correctly answered a question). If you have any inquiries about my answer, before that, please do ask.

Comment: Sure. It answers the question completely. I have small question regarding rcx and image name offset just to confirm that this register can be used to capture image name as well but JS script answers completely the question for sure. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @user1939837 If you look at the function signature you can see that rcx (1st param) is the `ProcessHandle` and it is an `out` paramter (it's valid only at function exit). You could use `!handle` to get the process name from that but in a script you would need to parse the command output which is sub-optimal IMHO (and getting an object name from a handle by parsing Windows' internal structs is a nightmare). The fact that you would need to wait for function exit to do that might also problematic. From my PoV, it's easier to do all the checks at function entry, but you might beg to differ.